# How To Open Application or calling screen When App is killed and get Firebase PushNotification without Tap on Notification in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-notifications

i am very new to flutter and
i want to open calling screen or hall application when Application is killed and Firebase PushNotification arrive without Tap ON Notification.
i have done all possible solution like try to open app in firebase notification creation even i have used Flutter_callkit_incomming library it is working fine when application is in background and screen or accept reject notification arrive but when application is killed and we press accept or reject button it seems not working. is there any  way to do it?

Comment: You have to wake your app using firebase background notification

Comment: but it will only work when app is in background not when app is killed right??@Md.KamrulAmin

Comment: No dear. If you implement background Notification properly it will also work when app is killed by user. When User A calls User B in your app, you have to send a firebase notification to User B. If the app is closed or not running in User B's phone. Firebase will wake the app up and fire the notification where you can make call notifications like facebook messenger.

Comment: please can you give example or any documentation for it please it will be very help full -@Md.KamrulAmin

Comment: https://medium.com/@alaa07996/firebase-push-notifications-with-flutter-6848892a1c15
This is a long recently written article for push notification. Firstly, you need your app to open from notification when app is killed. If that works and if you go through the article you will understand on how to handle calls when app is killed. If you still face problems, feel free to ask or post a new question. The community is always there to suggest or help you. Enjoy coding

Comment: thank you so much...i will let you know if it works @Md.KamrulAmin

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in Android but Its not possible in iOS for now, For android its **Full-screen intent notifications** and for iOS most you can do is set an custom ringtone when notification is received, You can use the below mentioned library for most of your notification needs:-[pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)